# Get JSON POST data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, forms, post

im new in C#.
How to get JSON POST data?
I have an service that POST JSON data to my asp.net.

Here the data:

```
{
   "transaction_time": "2017-09-18 09:47:54",
   "transaction_status": "capture",
   "transaction_id": "b7c8cfa9-b706-4a9d-b70d-8d70149145bd",
   "status_message": "Veritrans payment notification",
   "status_code": "200",
   "signature_key": "b22b5740bf2c587ba949ae5343757a66e5a75c45b9377b9ee891909bbd8977bb2caea8e0549bf09b5040b22f54efc76aa8beb31e321f9d600f267b23f37b30ae",
   "payment_type": "credit_card",
   "order_id": "LUHUMMLWOT",
   "masked_card": "401111-1112",
   "gross_amount": "326000.00",
   "fraud_status": "accept",
   "bank": "mandiri",
   "approval_code": "1505702878234"
 }
```

As far I know, I can catch all data using WebMethod, create an method then initialize the parameter each JSON object, but every post, they send different JSON. So I must get all JSON and parse it into variable dynamically.

Please help :)

Thanks~

Comment: Do you mean *how to get JSON POST data in your C# code function*?

Comment: have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJson)` you will need to include the `using Newtonsoft.Json;` statement in your code.

Comment: Yes @souvik, I dont know how to get JSON POST data in code behind of asp.net

Comment: Please check these links- https://forums.asp.net/t/2097621.aspx?Passing+Json+Object+to+codebehind+in+c+ and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/. It has step-by-step details.

Comment: So, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   **Pleas do it step by step as below
    in Your Asp.net Java script using**



var yourPostJsonObject={
   "transaction_time": "2017-09-18 09:47:54",
   "transaction_status": "capture",
   "transaction_id": "b7c8cfa9-b706-4a9d-b70d-8d70149145bd",
   "status_message": "Veritrans payment notification",
   "status_code": "200",
   "signature_key": "b22b5740bf2c587ba949ae5343757a66e5a75c45b9377b9ee891909bbd8977bb2caea8e0549bf09b5040b22f54efc76aa8beb31e321f9d600f267b23f37b30ae",
   "payment_type": "credit_card",
   "order_id": "LUHUMMLWOT",
   "masked_card": "401111-1112",
   "gross_amount": "326000.00",
   "fraud_status": "accept",
   "bank": "mandiri",
   "approval_code": "1505702878234"
 }


$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: 'SendTransaction', // webmethod or web serivces URL
                data: {jsonReceiverInCsharpObjecName:JSON.stringify(yourPostJsonObject)},
                success: function (response) {
                   alert('scucess')
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

**in Asp.net Code behind or webservice**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public bool SendTransaction(string jsonReceiverInCsharpObjecName)
 {
   dynamic dynData =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>
   (jsonReceiverInCsharpObjecName, new ExpandoObjectConverter());

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> transItem in dynData 
{
   if (transItem.Key == "transaction_time")
   var transaction_time = Convert.ToString(transItem.Value);
   else if (transItem.Key == "transaction_status")
   var transaction_status = Convert.ToString(transItem.Value);
   else if (transItem.Key == "transaction_id")
   var transaction_ido = Convert.ToString(transItem.Value);
   //else
   //do for rest attribute of your json data
 }

return true;
 }
```

Comment: The C# code makes no sense, where are you extracting the json data from the request?

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse your json in a dynamic object if you do not know about what json is coming.

You can use the dynamic object like this.

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

in you case you can get the data like this.

```
string transaction_time=data.transaction_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use object instead of dynamic, and then use reflection to get all the properties in json object, I can give you generic code example, you can search on Reflection for more understanding

```
public void GetData(object obj)
{
    foreach(var item in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
         Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ":\t" + item.GetValue(obj));
    }
}
```

You can use it whatever the way you want

Answer (score -1):

**Post using C#**

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/api/subject");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n        \"author\": "Balu\",\n        \"title\": \"Post using C#\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: No, I mean, how to get JSON POST data, not POST JSON data to C#